# FragmentManager's asynchronization

Tags: android, fragment

My project was working fine in Eclipse, but since I migrated my project to AndroidStudio, I have been getting this weird `NullPointerException` that I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Specifically `fragment.getView()` always return `null` for whatever reason.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
    }

    switchFragment(fragment, position);
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, int position){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
    fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

The problem is at line `fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`. I thought that when `FragmentManager` commit `fragment` then its view should have been created, but apparently I'm wrong. I tried to look it up but cannot find any satisfactory explanation. Please help me fix this. Below is my `Fragment1` class:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
} 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, parent, false);
}


}
```

Comment: You have to wait till the fragment is attached to the activity

Comment: it happens cause you try get reference on fragment root view while view not attached on fragment.

You can call getView() only after onCreateView()

Answer (score 1):

Fragment transactions are executed asynchronously. Think of it like it was a runnable posted to the UI thread message queue.

In particular, `getView()` will return whatever you returned from `onCreateView()` but only after the lifecycle method has been called. Before it returns null.

You should put the view customization such as `setFocusableInTouchMode()` to the fragment itself. `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` are good places.

Nothing to do with Android Studio. It works the same way in both IDEs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Where do you think I should put `getView().setOnKeyListener`? I put this in `MainActivity` such that if the current fragment is not `Fragment1` but rather `Fragment2`, then if I press the `back` button, `FragmentTransaction` will destroy `Fragment2` and attach `Fragment1`. But now `getView()` always return `null`... I wondered when it changed though I have been able to call `getView()` in `MainActivity` before without these async problem

Comment: Put the key listener assignments in the fragment.